# Excel - INDEX / MATCH with different tables and multiple criterias

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two Excel Sheets

Sheet 1:

[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 2:

[image: Sheet 2]

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get excel to retrieve the date in the top row for the column that contains a value. I think I have found a way to do this without taking the Unique ID in account but I need to be able to add the ID as a criteria into this formula because my formula would only work if all the IDs are in the same order and part of both tables.

This is what I currently got : =INDEX($H$4:$Z$4;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(H6:Z6>0;0);0))

How can I take into consideration the IDs in a way that excel matches the IDs also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IFERROR(EOMONTH(AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(INDEX($H$5:$Z$16,MATCH($G22,$G$5:$G$16,0),)<>"")*($H$4:$Z$4),1),0),"")`

Older versions of Excel need this entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`.

This searches your data for the row where the ID meets the criteria (in this example I used `G22` for the ID to match).
Aggregate checks for a non-empty cell in that range and returns the value in the header. EOMONTH then returns the last day of that month.
If there's no values or matching ID's it returns as blank.

[image]

Comment: Thats great help thank you!